# MySQL Select range date between two columns without using table columns

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, between

In My sql I want to get the date differences between two dates without using table columns
For example

```
SELECT BETWEEN '2012-01-10' AND '2012-01-15' as date1;
```

I have to get the following date as output
'2012-01-11'
'2012-01-12'
'2012-01-13'
'2012-01-14'

how to write a query to get the output as above

Comment: As you can see from the answers, it is worth considering upgrading to MySQL 8. Older versions lack features that we expect from a modern RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT @startdate + INTERVAL 1 DAY `date`
         UNION ALL
         SELECT `date`+ INTERVAL 1 DAY
         FROM cte 
         WHERE `date` < @enddate - INTERVAL 1 DAY )
SELECT * 
FROM cte
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2df73791a21b3e57eb4ab204e3fb190e)

MySQL 8+ needed.

---

> my sql version used 5.6

> maximum 1 year

```
SELECT @startdate + INTERVAL (n3.num * 7 * 7 + n2.num * 7 + n1.num + 1) DAY `date`
FROM  ( SELECT 0 num union select 1 union select 2 union select 3
       union select 4 union select 5 union select 6) n1
JOIN  ( SELECT 0 num union select 1 union select 2 union select 3
       union select 4 union select 5 union select 6) n2
JOIN  ( SELECT 0 num union select 1 union select 2 union select 3
       union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7) n3
HAVING `date` < @enddate;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dfea50c215ffde9f3b110b2c7f9bca34)

Max. period length is 7 * 7 * 8 = 392 days.

Comment: my sql version used 5.6 and I have tried the following query but it does not return the correct answer when we use the date difference more than 3 months

SELECT '2020-09-01' + INTERVAL a + b DAY AS date_selected
FROM
(SELECT 0 a UNION SELECT 1 a UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7
UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) d,
(SELECT 0 b UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 20
UNION SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 40) m
WHERE '2020-09-01' + INTERVAL a + b DAY < '2021-11-20'
ORDER BY a + b;

Comment: @Nishanth *my sql version used 5.6* You should have written it in capital letters at the very beginning of the question. This is critical! Anycase - what is practical maximum of the period length in days?

Comment: Periods will be based on user choice. They may go for maximum 1 year

Comment: @Nishanth Variant for your version added.

Comment: Incase if we want to increase to more than 2 years, do we need to add one more join
for example if the start date is '2015-09-01'

Comment: @Nishanth Expand last subquery till 15 or add one more number-generating level subquery (and edite the expression accordingly). You may use any base on any level - simply avoid final number duplication.

Comment: @Nishanth: Try to understand what this query is doing. Akina creates dummy tables on-the-fly holding the numbers 0-7, 0-7, and 0-8, so cross joining them and some math gets you numbers 0 to 7 x 7 x 8 - 1 = 391. He could just as well have created one table with these numbers straight away. Only this would have been more typing. You can do this with more or less tables consisting of more or less rows. Just see what you need and how you want this be done. It should be `CROSS JOIN` by the way, not `[INNER] JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with a recursive query:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select '2012-01-10' + interval 1 day as dt
    union all 
    select dt + interval 1 day from cte where dt + interval 1 day < '2012-01-15'
)
select * from cte
```

This generates one row per date in between the bounds given as input.

Comment: @Akina: Thanks. I am mistaking sometimes about the `recursive` keyword, because some databases require it and others don't: eg MySQL wants it, SQL Server doesn't, in Postgres it's optional...